# use $(this) in ajax callback jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm doing a `jQuery.post` to a php file, and the file return's me a value.

the question is: why the `$(this)` dosent work in the callback function ?
any alert passing something to show, using `$(this)`, return's me `null`

```
$(".class").live("focusout", function(){

    jQuery.post("phpfile.php",
       {
           someValue: someValue
       },
       function(data)
       {
             // why the $(this) dosent work in the callback ?
       }                

    )

});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In that case `this` is not the same object anymore. Save a reference before and use later:

```
$(".class").live("focusout", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    jQuery.post("phpfile.php",
       {
           someValue: someValue
       },
       function(data)
       {
           // 'this' inside this scope refers to xhr object (wrapped in jQuery object)
           var x = $this;
       }                
    )
});
```

Comment: Preferably, use [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of `.post()` so you can set the `context` option.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".class").live("focusout", function(){
    var this = $(this);
    jQuery.post("phpfile.php",{
       someValue: someValue
   },function(data){
        // Now use this instead of $(this), like this.hide() or whatever.
   })
});
```

$(this) in your example was refering to the $.post i think.

Comment: Add a `var` declaration before your `this` call or it will leak the `this` variable into the global scope.