# jQuery Hovercard AJAX Load

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have been attempting to integrate jQuery hovercard (http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard) with our web application. We need it to display HTML received from an AJAX page when hovering over a username link identified with the data attribute data-toggle="user".

This is our code so far...

```
$('a[data-toggle="user"]').hovercard({
  detailsHTML: 'Loading user details...',
  width: 350,
  cardImgSrc: 'http://ejohn.org/files/short.sm.jpg', //Dummy URL for now
  onHoverIn: function() {
    // set your twitter id
    var user = 'jeresig';

    $.ajax({
      url: '/components/users/_hovercards/user-hovercard.php',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'text',
      beforeSend: function() {
        $(this).text("Loading...");
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $(this).empty();
        $(this).text(data);
      },
      complete: function() {

      },
      error: function() {
        //$(this).text("An error occured in loading the user hovercard");
        $(this).text("An error occured loading the user data...");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The issue is that this does not append the HTML from the AJAX page to the hovercard. I have tried a few changes to diagnose the fault and when I explicitly call the $(this) value and attempt to manually change it outside the AJAX lines to test appending the data manually I wind up replacing the link data itself with the manually appended html and the hovercard does not display.

I have used the global selector in a few spots in my code to apply events to all elements with a particular data-toggle value and use the $(this) selector with no issue but in this instance I am having issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you `$(this)` is not the same as `$('a[data-toggle="user"]')`within the `$.ajax` call. Instead, the `$(this)` refers to the AJAX object, which will not do anything.

Here's a modified solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6307041/2397327):

```
$('a[data-toggle="user"]').hovercard({
  ...
  var elem = $(this);
  $.ajax( ...
    success: function(data) {
      elem.empty();
      elem.text(data);
    } ...
    error: function() {
      elem.text("An error occured loading the user data...");
    }
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: This put me on the right track. Once I dug a bit deeper into the javascript modified HTML I found that I actually needed to take the html returned by the AJAX connection and place it into the child element of the $(this), so with a slight tweak I got it working by declaring the elem object as elem = $(this).children("div") as the hovercard plugin created one div element under the parent element which contained all of the html used in the hovercard.

Comment: @PlanetScaleNetworks I'm glad I helped and it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

You are so close! The only change you need to make is to use:

```
.html('html');
```

or

```
.append('html');
```

In your SUCCESS setting within your ajax call definition!

Note that this will load HTML into the DOM as well as execute any `<script>` tags in your Ajax response! I've done this a lot in applications I've written. Let me know if you have any questions!

You can find more information here:

.html() ---  http://api.jquery.com/html/

.append() --- http://api.jquery.com/append/